# Automatic Downcasting

Tags: java, frameworks

I'm making a framework in Java and have a method in my abstract class, BasicPhase, called processAction (snippet below). It takes two abstract classes as parameters since the user should implement them in child classes. However, it results in the user being required to constantly downcast every time they override the method. How can this be avoided?

BasicPhase.java

```
public class BasicPhase {
    ...
    public BasicGameState processAction(BasicAction action, BasicGameState state);
    ...
}
```

Example User Class

MyPhase.java

```
public class MyPhase extends BasicPhase {
    @Override
    public BasicGameState processAction(BasicAction basicAction, BasicGameState basicState)  {
        MyGameState state = (MyGameState) basicState; //undesired
        MyAction action = (MyAction) basicAction; //undesired

        //Game Logic Here
    }
}
```

Comment: As you are showing it, there is no way for a compiler or a programmer to ensure or validate that processAction invoked on a MyPhase instance is being passed a MyGameState action.  Thus, the casts are strictly necessary, and, may fail at runtime.  There is not enough surrounding context to understand how to address this.  The context required goes to who calls processAction, and what they do with the state and actions.  I think that any potential solution will involve refactoring the invocation of this method and where the state is stored/passed, maybe applying a design pattern like Strategy.

Comment: what you're looking for is a generic class to inherit where the generic parameters are the types of action and game state the phase accepts - `processAction` clearly *cannot* work on the *base* action and state types, so you need to make the types that need to be passed as parameters *strongly specified*. Do this by making `BasicPhase` a `BasicPhase<TAction, TState>` and the `processAction` a `processAction(TAction action, TState state)`

Answer (score 5):

`processAction` clearly *cannot* work on the *base* action and state types, so you need to make the types that need to be passed as parameters specifically the types that `processAction` *can* work with. To make the parameter types definable by your derived classes, you need to make the base class generic such that the generic parameters are the types of action and game state the phase accepts.

Do this by making `BasicPhase` a

```
public class BasicPhase<TAction extends BasicAction, TState extends BasicGameState>
```

and the `processAction` a `processAction(TAction action, TState state)` then your `MyPhase` would derive as:

```
public class MyPhase extends BasicPhase<MyAction, MyGameState> {
```

Comment: Hm, from what the OP wrote I assume he wants his framework to hold a list of `BasicPhase` (or derived) objects which is created at run time and call `processAction` for each of the objects in the list. I think that will be not so easy with your suggestion.

Comment: @DocBrown while I agree you the consumer would need to know the type of the phase to execute it in this case (it would need to be a `List<BasicPhase<MyAction, MyGameState>>`) I don't see any mention of the list in his question - also you have to realize whoever's calling `processAction` *already has knowledge of MyAction and MyGameState* and therefore must *know* it's calling a `MyPhase` because otherwise the `processAction` will throw an exception on the downcast..

Comment: I agree, we are guessing around here how the code the OP did not show us might look like - maybe the lack of information is leading us to wrong assumptions.

Answer (score 4):

If `MyPhase.progressAction` would exclusively call methods available in `BasicAction` or `BasicGameState`, then there would be no need for any downcast. Those methods might be ordinary methods or methods overridden in `MyAction` and/or `MyGameState`. So you should consider to change the design of `BasicAction`, `BasicGameState` and/or `progressAction` to make this possible.

Note, as @ErikEidt correctly stated in his comment, that this may not be the best or most sensible solution for your case, since you gave us not enough information to allow any better advice.

Comment: I came back to write just this.  Damn you for stealing my upvote (although I'm the upvoter here)!